# What is the "weak global reference table"?

Tags: java, android

After playing a video in the `WebView` on `Android` for a bit I get this crash. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong on my end since I can't reproduce it on other `WebView` browsers but first I want to understand what the `weak global reference table` is? is it for `WeakRerefence` instances?

Thanks.

```
 java_vm_ext.cc:662] JNI ERROR (app bug): weak global reference table overflow (max=51200)weak global reference table dump:
 java_vm_ext.cc:662]   Last 10 entries (of 51200):
 java_vm_ext.cc:662]     51199: 0x1d040028 java.lang.Thread
 java_vm_ext.cc:662]     51198: 0x1d000028 java.lang.Thread
 java_vm_ext.cc:662]     51197: 0x1cfc0028 java.lang.Thread
 java_vm_ext.cc:662]     51196: 0x1cf80028 java.lang.Thread
 java_vm_ext.cc:662]     51195: 0x1cf40028 java.lang.Thread
 java_vm_ext.cc:662]     51194: 0x1cf00028 java.lang.Thread
 java_vm_ext.cc:662]     51193: 0x1cec0028 java.lang.Thread
 java_vm_ext.cc:662]     51192: 0x1ce80028 java.lang.Thread
 java_vm_ext.cc:662]     51191: 0x1ce40028 java.lang.Thread
 java_vm_ext.cc:662]     51190: 0x1cdc0028 java.lang.Thread
 java_vm_ext.cc:662]   Summary:
 java_vm_ext.cc:662]     26835 of java.lang.Thread (26832 unique instances)
 java_vm_ext.cc:662]     22377 of java.lang.Class (22377 unique instances)
 java_vm_ext.cc:662]      1395 of com.facebook.stetho.server.LocalSocketServer$WorkerThread (1395 unique instances)
 java_vm_ext.cc:662]       228 of java.util.TimerThread (227 unique instances)
```

Edit: Just to be clear, I've seen a few answers about the `global reference table` but not about the **weak** `global reference table`.

Edit: it appears that the crash only happens while the app is being debugged.

Comment: I am facing the same issue in Android 9. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I think it was an issue that only happened while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from Stephen Nelson

> Your code is failing because you have too many global references to
>   objects that have not been released back into the memory pool

Here is the link to the link for the full answer [Why do I need to release global references created in JNI native functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143101/why-do-i-need-to-release-global-references-created-in-jni-native-functions/36143581#36143581)

Comment: Thanks, I had seen that but their log doesn't have `weak`, so I'm wondering if mine is for `WeakRerefence` specifically?